# How to get timestamp of next specific weekday in the future?

Tags: scala

I am trying to calculate the difference between current timestamp and some known date/time in the future.  So, how to to get timestamp of say, next Sunday 10:30 PM EST in Scala?

Comment: What have you already tried (code)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you get a `DateTime` for the current moment, then adjust it to the target moment.

```
import java.time._

val now  = LocalDateTime.now
val days = (DayOfWeek.SUNDAY.getValue + 7 - now.getDayOfWeek.getValue) % 7
val soon = now.toLocalDate.plusDays(days).atTime(13,20)  //1:20PM, next Sunday
```

This assumes no adjustment in Time Zone.

To get the difference between them you have to decide how you want to measure it.

```
import java.time.temporal.ChronoUnit._

DAYS.between(now,soon)     //4
HOURS.between(now,soon)    //113
MINUTES.between(now,soon)  //6832
```